# You can't specify target table xxxx for update in FROM clause, tratando de actualizar una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Traté de actualizar el campo **score** de mi tabla **dpartida** pero me manda error:

> code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'dpartida' for update in
> FROM clause

Les dejo mi sentencia

```
use noble;
update dpartida 
   set score=1 
   where idpartida=
      (select p.idpartida from dpartida p 
       inner join dpersona m on p.idpartida=m.idpartida 
       inner join musuario u on m.idpersona = u.idpersona where u.nomusuario="qwe");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En *MySQL* no se puede referenciar a la tabla sobre la que se está haciendo una modificación (`insert`, `update` o `delete`) dentro de una subconsulta.

Para evitar este error, puedes forzar a crear una tabla temporal haciendo la subconsulta así:

```
update dpartida set score=1 where idpartida=
select p.idpartida from (select * from dpartida) p inner join ...
```

De todos modos en el caso concreto de tu consulta creo que es más fácil realizarla con el `join` directamente en el `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE dpartida p
INNER JOIN dpersona m ON p.idpartida = m.idpartida 
INNER JOIN musuario u ON m.idpersona = u.idpersona 
SET p.score = 1
WHERE u.nomusuario = "qwe"
```